# Select dates in asp.net Calendar programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I'm using `Calendar` controller in my asp.net web forms application. I followed [this article](http://jayeshsorathia.blogspot.com/2012/09/beginning-net-multiple-selection-of-date-in-calendar-control.html) to implement `Calendar` in my application. I'm adding selected days into a `List<DateTime>` to remember selected dates and use them in future actions.

Now I have added buttons to my page like `Select Weekends`, `Select Weekdays`, `Select Month` and `Select Year`.

- if I click on the `Select Weekends` button, I need to select all weekend days of current month and add them into `List<DateTime>`.
- if I click on the `Select Weekdays` button, I need to select all week days of current month and add them into `List<DateTime>`.
- if I click on the `Select Month`** button, I need to select all days of the current month and add them into `List<DateTime>`.
- if I click on the `Select Year` button, I need to select all days of the current year and add them into `List<DateTime>`.

How can I do this programatically using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a miracle solution, here how I would write 2 methods to what you want for the weekend days. For the other points, you could do more or less the same thing:

```
    protected void WeekendDays_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectWeekEnds():
    }

    private void SelectWeekEnds(){
        //If you need to get the selected date from calendar
        //DateTime dt = this.Calendar1.SelectedDate;

        //If you need to get the current date from today
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

        List<DateTime> weekendDays = this.SelectedWeekEnds(dt);
        weekendDays.ForEach(d => this.Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(d));
    }

    private List<DateTime> GetWeekEndDays(DateTime DT){
        List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();
        int month = DT.Month;
        DT = DT.AddDays(-DT.Day+1);//Sets DT to first day of month

        //Sets DT to the first week-end day of the month;
        if(DT.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            while (DT.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                DT = DT.AddDays(1);

        //Adds the week-end day and stops when next month is reached.
        while (DT.Month == month)
        {
            result.Add(DT);
            DT = DT.AddDays(DT.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ? 1 : 6);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I need to change back color of selected dates. how can i do this ?

Comment: Example: this.Calendar1.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

Comment: can you explain this line please ? `DT = DT.AddDays(DT.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ? 1 : 6);`. i'm trying to get week days. but still unable to do it correctly.

Comment: If guess you may have a look at the ternary operator definition: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx If DT.DayOfWeek is Saturday, this line increments DT by 1 day, if DT.DayOfWeek is Sunday, it adds 6 days to get to the next Saturday. I did not write a complete solution for your 4 different points, I just wanted to show a way to go, you may have to do consequent changes in the logic to write the other methods (I mean not just copy/paste and change a few things).

Comment: I have modified your code to get week days. but it is not working properly. i have added it as [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397397/select-week-days-in-asp-net-calendar-programatically) . can you look at it ?